# mouseEnter and mouseLeave not working on ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a pretty simple component. Basically when I hover over it I want it to set the 'showTooltip' property based on the component to true, and when I hover off, I set it back to false. For whatever reason this doesn't seem to be working, and for the foggiest cannot figure out why (seeing as I have a click event on there too and that works fine as well). I'm runnimg Ember 2.8.

```
mouseEnter() {
 this.set('showTooltip', true);
 return false;
},

mouseLeave() {
 this.set('showTooltip', false);
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/923daa2110f1260d60c6e62be97ac541?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) for you. It is working on 2.8.

You should care about some situations:

- event handlers are not written in "actions" hash.
- component must not be a "tagless" component. (Don't override tagName with undefined/null)

If you provide a twiddle, we may look further.